# PHP code does not run

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to run a PHP code by the click of a button, but it does not seem to work. I'm running this on a MAPM server.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <div onClick="count();">Click!</div>
    <script>
function count() {
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'count.php');
    xhr.send();
}​
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

In the PHP file (count.php) we have this code:

```
<?php
Print "Hello, World!";
?>
```

Comment: Is the URL correct? or will it be "/count.php"?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"? The script has no side effects and you're not doing anything with the output, so nothing would happen even if the request succeeded. Is this the real code?

Answer (score 2):

you need your page to listen to the request;

```
function count() {
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange =     function (){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200){
            // WHAT HAPPENS ON SUCCESS
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }else{
                alert('timeout error or something');
        }
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'count.php');
    xhr.send();
}​;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `null` to the `send()` method like below (also be sure that the URL is correct, my hunch is that it should be "/count.php"):

```
xhr.send(null) // it's a GET request
```

For a detailed tutorial, check out this MDN doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Pass "true" as the third parameter to your `xhr.open()` call, like this `xhr.open('GET', '/count.php', true);`

Comment: Okay, if you have Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, can you inspect and see what are you getting as the response status of your request? If it is 404 then the URL is not correct, if the response is 200 then it is working (your PHP code is working fine), if it is 500 then there's an exception on your server, please dig further into it.

Comment: Nothing happens. I have no idea why.